# iOS Dropbox API - Re-Authenticating (Error 401)

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api

I've been having issues with my iOS App using Dropbox. It used to run with the Dropbox Core API perfectly fine, with no problems uploading a file, but now it'll show me an error 401. I've seen everywhere that all I need is to re-authenticate. Sorry if this question sounds dumb, but what is meant by re-authentication here and how do I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Dropbox SDK - Cannot upload or get metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325875/ios-dropbox-sdk-cannot-upload-or-get-metadata)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to login to Dropbox again.

Answer (score 1):

For re-authentication first of all unlink your session using below code.

```
              [[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];
```

hope it will work for you @Oscar.