# iOS Dropbox SDK - Cannot upload or get metadata

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, dropbox, dropbox-api

This app used to work properly, but now I cannot upload a file or get metadata. Whenever I try to upload, I'll get

```
File upload failed with error: Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 401.)"
```

But when trying to get metadata I'll get

```
Error loading metadata: Error Domain=dropbox.com Code=403 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (dropbox.com error 403.)"
```

I've been trying to re-authenticate, but there seems to be no difference after I execute unlink command. I've tried placing this command in different places.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
//[[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];
DBSession *dbSession = [[DBSession alloc]
                        initWithAppKey:@"**********" //AppKey
                        appSecret:@"************" //Secret
                        root:kDBRootDropbox]; // kDBRootAppFolder or kDBRootDropbox
[DBSession setSharedSession:dbSession];
[[DBSession sharedSession] unlinkAll];
return YES;
}
```

It also seems like it's not accessing the authentication flow method thing:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)source annotation:(id)annotation {
if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
        NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
        // At this point you can start making API calls
    }
    return YES;
}
// Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
return NO;
}
```

I've been following the instructions in the Dropbox documentation and can't seem to find what's wrong.

EDIT: This is where I call linkFromController inside my ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
self.restClient.delegate = self;

if (![[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
    [[DBSession sharedSession] linkFromController:self];
}

}
```

Comment: When/where are you calling `linkFromController` to auth the user?

Comment: Editted that part above. It's inside my ViewController

Comment: So when you call `linkFromController`, are you prompted to authorize with your Dropbox account? Also, when you say "It also seems like it's not accessing the authentication flow method thing:", are you saying that that part of your code isn't being executed?

Comment: It used to send me to the Dropbox authorization page at first, but not anymore. And yes, it seems like it isn't being executed. I placed some NSLog() in there and the messages weren't shown on the console.

Comment: Could it have something to do with my account?

Comment: Hmm just noticed an error -1005... `File upload failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)" `
No idea what this error means...

Comment: This error seems to mean "Network Connection Lost", but no idea as to why this happens.

Comment: Let's debug one problem at a time. :-) If you're not being sent to the Dropbox authorization page, something must be wrong with your call to `linkFromController`. Are you sure `linkFromController` is being called?

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure I'm calling it... just not executing.

Comment: Ok, so I removed it from the `viewDidLoad` and added a button, which called `linkFromController` from there... it did make me log in to Dropbox, but I still wasn't able to upload the file.

Comment: It looks like you're creating your `restClient` before actually linking a user. That could be the problem. I'd suggest following the sample code that ships with the SDK as closely as possible until you get things working.